# Schedule disk scan for Ubuntu boot

Tags: ubuntu, scheduled-tasks, scan-disk

How can I schedule a disk scan for the next boot in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

forces a file system check on the next start up. Use the *tune2fs* program if you want to change the check frequency, see its man page for how to use it.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to only perform a very short scan. Is there a way to do a more comprehensive scan?